# Overly verbose XML when serializing interfaces with the DataContractResolver

Tags: .net, datacontractserializer

I've shortened the question drastically as I've gotten no answers so far.

Basically I'm trying to serialize interfaces with the DataContractSerializer. But when using the DataContractResolver to do this, the generated XML is really verbose. I have an interface IAnimal and a concrete implementation Cat.

If I just serialize Cat I get the XML:

```
<Cat xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestDataContractResolver.Concrete" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Species>feline</Species>
  <Weight>1</Weight>
</Cat>
```

However, when serializing IAnimal with the help of a DataContractResolver, I get the following XML:

```
<z:anyType i:type="a:TestDataContractResolver.Concrete.Cat" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="TestDataContractResolver.Concrete, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
  <Species xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestDataContractResolver.Concrete">feline</Species>
  <Weight xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestDataContractResolver.Concrete">1</Weight>
</z:anyType>
```

Which is rediculously verbose. Why is it sticking xmlns's into every property element, not just the root element? And how do I make it not do that?

By the way, here is my implementation for the DataContractSerializer, based on [Youssef Moussaoui's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/06/05/introducing-a-new-datacontractserializer-feature-the-datacontractresolver.aspx):

```
public class ModelDataContractResolver : DataContractResolver
    {
        public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
        {
            return knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, declaredType, null) ?? Type.GetType(typeName + ", " + typeNamespace);
        }

        public override bool TryResolveType(Type type, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, out XmlDictionaryString typeName, out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
        {
            if (knownTypeResolver.TryResolveType(type, declaredType, null, out typeName, out typeNamespace))
            {
                return true;
            }

            XmlDictionary dictionary = new XmlDictionary();
            typeName = dictionary.Add(type.FullName);
            typeNamespace = dictionary.Add(type.Assembly.FullName);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your objective here to get xml? or is it to serialize/deserialize the interface construct? I might be able to do it cleanly, but with a different serializer (and not `BinaryForamtter` / `NetDataContractSerializer`, which are cheating)

Comment: @Marc, I haven't researched it sufficiently in depth. I'm definitely open to non-xml options, but ultimately I need to support versioning issues, which are generally easier with XML. Are you thinking protobuf?

Comment: you read my mind :) protobuf is also designed to be easily versioned

Comment: I'll look into it then. Can it serialize interfaces without requiring attributes on the interfaces?

Comment: protobuf-net v2 can, yes - but I'd need to see a concrete example to fill in the blanks